# 'ImportError: No module named ' , flask on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask

[image]

I am working on a flask app with a structure as in the screenshot based on http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-pythons-flask-framework--net-28822. To get this working locally I've been running the routes.py file.

I'm now trying to deploy on heroku using gunicorn following https://www.udacity.com/wiki/ud330/deploy. Following the directions, My requirements.txt contains:

```
$ pip Freeze
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Mail==0.9.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.1
Flask-WTF==0.12
Jinja2==2.8
MarkupSafe==0.23
SQLAlchemy==1.0.11
WTForms==2.1
Werkzeug==0.11.3
blinker==1.4
gunicorn==19.4.5
itsdangerous==0.24
```

I'm not sure what to put into my Procfile , I've tried several variations including:

```
web: gunicorn mini:intro_to_flask
```

But I'm getting the following in the heroku logs:

```
←[32m2016-01-23T17:15:39.572265+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m ImportError: No module named mi
ni
←[32m2016-01-23T17:15:39.652562+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     super(Application, self).ru
n()
←[32m2016-01-23T17:15:39.652583+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib
/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
←[32m2016-01-23T17:15:39.652835+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib
/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 347, in stop
←[32m2016-01-23T17:15:39.572260+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib
/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
←[32m2016-01-23T17:15:39.652807+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     self.stop()
←[32m2016-01-23T17:15:39.652914+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     time.sleep(0.1)
←[32m2016-01-23T17:15:39.653207+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <Ha
ltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
←[32m2016-01-23T17:15:40.600197+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from starting
to crashed
←[32m2016-01-23T17:15:40.576720+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited with status 1
```

Also my runserver.py file contains:

```
from intro_to_flask import app

app.run(debug=True)
```

How can I fix this?

edit changed Procfile to:

```
web: gunicorn runserver:app
```

Now getting:

```
←[32m2016-01-23T17:47:43.545434+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     from intro_to_flask import
app
←[32m2016-01-23T17:47:43.545435+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m ImportError: No module named in
tro_to_flask
←[32m2016-01-23T17:47:43.545435+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Traceback (most recent call las
t):
←[32m2016-01-23T17:47:43.545436+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib
/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 515, in spawn_worker
←[32m2016-01-23T17:47:43.545438+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib
/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 122, in init_process
←[32m2016-01-23T17:47:43.545437+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     worker.init_process()
←[32m2016-01-23T17:47:43.545438+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     self.load_wsgi()
←[32m2016-01-23T17:47:43.545439+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib
/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 130, in load_wsgi
←[32m2016-01-23T17:47:43.545440+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()

←[32m2016-01-23T17:47:43.545440+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib
/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
←[32m2016-01-23T17:47:43.545441+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     self.callable = self.load()

←[32m2016-01-23T17:47:43.545442+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib
/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
←[32m2016-01-23T17:47:43.545442+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     return self.load_wsgiapp()
←[32m2016-01-23T17:47:43.545443+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib
/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
←[32m2016-01-23T17:47:43.545444+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     return util.import_app(self
```

edit2:

made the change to a normal '__init__.py' . intro_to_flask now registering as a module:

```
←[36m2016-01-23T18:15:18.071418+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     from intro_to_flask import
app
←[36m2016-01-23T18:15:18.150803+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib
/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 74, in run
←[36m2016-01-23T18:15:18.150846+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [
OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
←[36m2016-01-23T18:15:18.071419+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m ImportError: cannot import name
 app
←[36m2016-01-23T18:15:18.071605+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [2016-01-23 18:15:18 +0000] [10
] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
←[36m2016-01-23T18:15:18.150976+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     Arbiter(self).run()
←[36m2016-01-23T18:15:18.150712+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Traceback (most recent call las
t):
←[36m2016-01-23T18:15:18.151078+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     self.halt(reason=inst.reaso
n, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
←[36m2016-01-23T18:15:18.150718+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/python/bin
/gunicorn", line 11, in <module>
←[36m2016-01-23T18:15:18.151098+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib
/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 302, in halt
←[36m2016-01-23T18:15:18.150773+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     sys.exit(run())
←[36m2016-01-23T18:15:18.151169+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     self.stop()
←[36m2016-01-23T18:15:18.151172+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib
/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 347, in stop
←[36m2016-01-23T18:15:18.151267+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     time.sleep(0.1)
←[36m2016-01-23T18:15:18.150869+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib
/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 192, in run
←[36m2016-01-23T18:15:18.151289+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib
/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 219, in handle_chld
←[36m2016-01-23T18:15:18.150923+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     super(Application, self).ru
n()
←[36m2016-01-23T18:15:18.151342+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     self.reap_workers()
←[36m2016-01-23T18:15:18.150943+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib
/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
←[36m2016-01-23T18:15:18.151362+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib
/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 464, in reap_workers
←[36m2016-01-23T18:15:18.150998+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib
/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 206, in run
←[36m2016-01-23T18:15:18.151520+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <Ha
ltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
←[36m2016-01-23T18:15:18.151455+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     raise HaltServer(reason, se
lf.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
←[36m2016-01-23T18:15:19.049307+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited with status 1

←[36m2016-01-23T18:15:19.061843+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from starting
to crashed
```

edit 3:

```
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910512+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     from intro_to_flask import
routes
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910513+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/intro_to_flask/rou
tes.py", line 123, in <module>
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910513+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     app.run()
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910514+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib
/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 772, in run
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910515+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     run_simple(host, port, self
, **options)
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910515+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib
/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 692, in run_simple
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910516+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     inner()
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910516+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib
/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 654, in inner
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910517+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     fd=fd)
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910518+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib
/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 548, in make_server
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910518+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     passthrough_errors, ssl_con
text, fd=fd)
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910519+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib
/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 462, in __init__
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910523+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     HTTPServer.__init__(self, (
host, int(port)), handler)
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910524+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib
/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 420, in __init__
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910525+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     self.server_bind()
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910526+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib
/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 108, in server_bind
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910526+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     SocketServer.TCPServer.serv
er_bind(self)
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910527+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib
/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 434, in server_bind
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910528+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     self.socket.bind(self.serve
r_address)
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910529+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib
/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910529+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     return getattr(self._sock,n
ame)(*args)
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910548+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m error: [Errno 98] Address alrea
dy in use
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910686+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [2016-01-23 19:14:56 +0000] [10
] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:57.199826+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from starting
to up
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are creating your application instance from flask in file intro_to_flask and name of your instance variable is app:

intro_to_flask.py

```
...
app = Flask()
...
```

Change the Procfile to this

```
web: gunicorn intro_to_flask:app
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing you need to point at is the `app` object, which as you show is inside the `runserver` file. So:

```
gunicorn runserver:app
```

Comment: You've got a weird file name in that module: it should be just `__init__.py`, without the `a`.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I fixed that but its still not working. please see edit 2.

Comment: I changed the runserver file to from intro_to_flask import routes routes.run(debug=True).  Now getting [0m error: [Errno 98] Address alrea dy in use. Please see edit 3.

Comment: Please give us more details about the code, specially where you define you application instance.